# OLE DB Data from PowerBI dataset with square bracket

Tags: excel, oledb, powerbi-datasource

My OLE DB Query is directly connected with PowerBI dataset and it is showing as follow

```
EVALUATE SELECTCOLUMNS(KEEPFILTERS('MI Data'),  
"Organisation Name", 'MI Data'[OrganisationName],
"Order Month", 'MI Data'[Order Month],  
"AccountName", 'MI Data'[AccountName],  
"Business Unit", 'MI Data'[Business Area],  
"Department", 'MI Data'[Department])
```

My problem is when data is exported to excel the column heading is in Square Bracket like [Organisation Name] etc. Is there a way we can remove these square bracket from the heading? Thanking you in advance